Irrigation installation
I just had irrigation installed.
The sprinklers are 6 feet away from tall trees that need lots of hydration in the summer.
I already lost two of them.
Is that distance ok?
They are called Arborvitae. They are very tall and against the fence. There are 6 of them next to each other.

May not change the answer much, but what type of trees are they?

They are called Arborvitae. They are very tall and against the fence. There are 6 of them next to each other.

How tall is very tall

Keep in mind, roots absorb water through the tip, not the side.
Your question is a little more complex than it might first seem. Trees have root systems that can reach down into the soil as deep as they are high, and their root systems spread out as far as the branches do. Also, different trees have different water requirements, this is because of the difference in the cellular density of the wood. So in order to properly address this question, I would need to know what type of trees and a rough estimation of their height and width.
For example, the average Pecan tree consumes 250 Gallons of water per day, can reach a height of sixty feet, and a radius of 16-20 feet. That is a lot of water to supply.
The real concern with your irrigation system is sprinkler system coverage, which basically means the sprinkler sprayage should overlap itself 100%. In actuality, it is more complex than this because of how sprinklers are designed and the gallons per minute they are designed to provide. This is something that is not commonly known.

They are called Arborvitae. They are tall

Fully grown: 20' x 10'. These trees are heavy drinkers. Water three times a week or more. At very minimum 1 gallon of water per foot. In ground drip irrigation is preferable. https://extension.usu.edu/forestry/resources/forest-products/ask-an-expert/arborvitaes

I would try to irrigate the root systems of the trees using a drip system.  Attempting to adequately irrigate an established tree using rotor heads and/or mist heads is not ideal as you waste a larger volume of water and it doesn't reach the root system properly.

I've got some trees that I let the yard sprinklers overspray the root zone and that gets them plenty.  Quite a few pecans and they do very well.  I've heard having the sprinkler too close to the trunk is not good.
